# Add css class to rails select helper in haml

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

Simple task. I want to add a css class on my following f.select tag in haml. I have tried this:

```
.field= f.select :sponsor_id, sponsors.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, {:class => "my-class"}
```

it doesn't throw an exception but also doesn't append the class to the select element. Tried without brackets, also no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want

```
.field= f.select :sponsor_id, sponsors.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, {}, {:class => "my-class"}
```

Note the extra curlies.

Check the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you remove it out of the brackets

```
.field= f.select :sponsor_id, sponsors.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, :class => "my-class"
```

or perhaps this,

```
.field= f.select :sponsor_id, sponsors.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }, {}, {:class => "my-class"}
```